# Show that $\mu(\{0\})=0$ iff $\mu$ is supported on $H\setminus\{0\}$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $H$ be a $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space and $\mu$ be a finite measure on $\mathcal B(H)$.

**Question 1**: I've read that $\mu(\{0\})=0$ iff "$\mu$ is supported on $H\setminus\{0\}$". I'm not sure how I really need to understand the latter claim; does it mean $\operatorname{supp}\mu\subseteq H\setminus\{0\}$ or $\operatorname{supp}\mu=H\setminus\{0\}$? In any case, how can we show the claim (or at least one of the implications)?

By definition $\operatorname{supp}\mu$ contains all $x\in H$ such that every open neighborhood $N$ of $x$ it holds $\mu(N)>0$.

On the one hand, I don't see why $\mu(\{0\})=0$ necessarily rules out that $0\in\operatorname{supp}\mu$.

On the other hand, if $0\in\operatorname{supp}\mu$, then $\mu(N)=0$ for some (actually all) open neighborhood(s) $N$ of $x$ and hence $0\le\mu(\{0\})\le\mu(N)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Support of a probability measure $\mu$ is defined as the complement of the largest open set $U$ with $\mu (U)=0$. The support is always a closed set.

So the support cannot be $H \setminus \{0\}$. It is not even true that the support is contained in $H \setminus \{0\}$ if $\mu \{0\}=0$. For example if $\mu$ is the standard Gaussian measure on the real line then $\mu \{0\}=0$ but the support is the entire real line.

I think what you have seen is  a vague statement which says that $\mu \{0\}=0$ iff $\mu (E)=\mu (E (\cap  H \setminus \{0\}))$ for every $E$. This statement does not use the definition of support of a measure.

Some people use a vague measure theoretic concept of support. They say $A$ is  **a support** of $\mu$ if $\mu (E\cap A^{c})=0$ for all $E$. Equivalently the measure of  any measurable subset of $A^{c}$ is $0$. In this terminology there is nothing like **the support** of $\mu$.